# Using properties files in spring-boot tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I have simple spring boot web service, where for configuration I use `.properties` files. As example for spring-mail configuration, I have separate file `mailing.properties` located in `src/main/resources/config/` folder.

in main application I include it using:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "config/mailing.properties" })
```

The problem appears when it comes to tests, I would like to use the same properties from this file, but when i try to use it, I get `fileNotFaundExeption`.

Question is:

- Should I have separate resources in my `src/test` folder, or it is possible to access resources from `src/main` folder, if yes, how?

**UPDATE added sources**

test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        testService.printing();
    }

}
```

service class:

```
    @Service
public class TestService
{
    @Value("${str.pt}")
    private int pt;

    public void printing()
    {
        System.out.println(pt);
    }
}
```

main app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = { "config/mailing.properties" })
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image: structure]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@TestPropertySource` annotation in your test class.

For example you have this attribute in your `mailing.properties` file:

`mailFrom=fromMe@mail.com`

Just annotate `@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")` on your test class.

You should be able to read out the property for example with the `@Value` annotation.

```
@Value("${fromMail}")
private String fromMail;
```

To avoid annotate this annotation on multiple test classes you can implement a superclass or [meta-annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-meta).

---

EDIT1:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private MailService mailService;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    String s = mailService.getMailFrom();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

MailService:

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    @Value("${mailFrom}")
    private String mailFrom;

    public String getMailFrom() {
        return mailFrom;
    }

    public void setMailFrom(String mailFrom) {
        this.mailFrom = mailFrom;
    }
}
```

DemoTestFile:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/mailing.properties")
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MailService mailService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String s = mailService.getMailFrom();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: but file `.properties` can stay in `src/main/resources...` no need to make  `src/test/resources...`?

Comment: yes, correct. I suppose you have your config like this `src/main/resources/config/mailing.properties`. If yes it should work

Comment: still get: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/config/mailing.properties]` also added simple sources, on which i tested your sollution

Comment: @Bublik just tried a new project build on your code and it works. Can you show your project structure. updated my answer with my test code

Comment: just added structure

Comment: why is your application.properties file under `/config` and not under `/resources`? Spring-boot standardly searches for application.properties in `/src/main/resoureces/`. The mailing.properties can be inside config.

Comment: it doesn't matter, problem is with `mailing.properties`. Moreover, `http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html` point 24.3.

Comment: I find the problem:
I do not know Why but if I use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)` which is deprecated, in case of @SpringBootTest everything works.